# How to build a regular expression for this String

Tags: java, regex, split

Hello there i am having trouble building a regular expression for this strings

```
TOWN                 ALe   Alx   Aus   Bau   Bem   Bra   Clq   Crk   DLk

AlbertLea              -     -    22     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
```

What i want is to split the string including all the spaces between each token not a space for example the split string array will be something like this

```
[TOWN                 ,ALe   ,Alx   ,Aus   ,Bau   ,Bem   ,Bra   ,Clq   ,Crk   ,DLk]



[AlbertLea              ,-     ,-    ,22     ,-     ,-     ,-     ,-     ,-     ,-     ]
```

thank you.

Comment: Possibly a simple [**`[\t ]+`**](https://regex101.com/r/uDaczB/1/) would do. You need to double escape backslashes in `Java`, so that it becomes `[\\t ]+`.

Comment: @Jan Maybe `\s+` would be better, as it matches every kind of whitespace

Comment: the expression [\\t ]+ will split after it counter a tab what i have is single random spaces between each token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a look ahead, with a look behind:

```
(?<=\s)(?=\S)
```

The look behind `(?<=\s)` matches just after a whitespace character.

The look ahead `(?=\S)` matches just before a non-whitespace character.

The combination matches between whitespace and non-whitespace characters.

See [live regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/xa1997A1jW), and [live java demo](https://ideone.com/oMb9wr).

Comment: Lookarounds are very expensive, see https://regex101.com/r/uDaczB/1 (92 steps) vs. https://regex101.com/r/uDaczB/2 (788 steps), that is 7x times more! (and not really needed here).

Comment: thank you so much that's what is was looking for. Can you please explain to  me what look ahead, and  look behind does?

Comment: @Adam a look ahead *asserts* with consuming input that the input that follows matches the look ahead's regex. Same for look behinds, but they assert what preceded.

Comment: @Jan we're talking microseconds here. You wouldn't be able to notice the difference. Get over it and move on to something else.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than split on what you don't want you can capture what you do want more easily / efficiently:

```
/(\S+[ \t]+)/
```

[Demo](http://(%5CS+[%20%5Ct]*))

Not that this captures spaces not including the `\n\n` you have in your example.